# Intellij Idea: Continuously asking for memory increase

Tags: intellij-idea, heap-memory, performance

My intellij idea is running very slow and keeps asking for more memory even when I have given it more than 4 GB. How do I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the ~/.IntellijIdea* folder that contained all the config and other information. This worked for me. Not sure if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Clean the system cache in IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html). This helps if you have been running the same instance of Idea for lots of projects with lots of different libraries...